# Google Chrome and Favicon

Tags: google-chrome, favicon

Ive created a 64x64 favicon for a site im making and its displaying fine. But then in Google Chrome when i press "Create Application Shortcut" it resizes the favicon down to [what looks like] 16x16 for the desktop/taskbar icon it makes. This looks really silly - so how do I make Chrome not resize it, and end up with a nice clear, non blurry icon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make an application not resize a 64x64 image when it's displaying it in a 16x16 space.

Are you using a real favicon.ico, or a different image format? ICO files can contain different images with different sizes and colour depths in the same file. Add a 16x16 that looks clear rather than blurry, and add it to the ICO file.

Comment: You misunderstand my question. Im not talking about where it displays it in the top left, im talking about when it creates a desktop/taskbar icon which is  easily 64x64 is size(windows 7), it still resizes it down to 16x16 and then stretches that up.
Im using a 64x64 png

Comment: Again, using an ICO will solve that, as ICO is the format used in this case, but it's having to do it's own (apparenly quite poor, from what you say) PNG2ICO conversion. Use an icon instead of a image, and you're sorted.

Answer (score 13):

Check out [How can I customize the appearance and function of Google Chrome shortcuts that point to my page?](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/webmasters-faq.html#customshortcuts) in the Google Chrome FAQ.

Short answer, it's a different sort of meta tag like this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="gmail_32x32.png" sizes="32x32"/>
<link rel="icon" href="gmail_48x48.png" sizes="48x48"/>
```

Comment: this should be marked as best answer as it directly solves the issue!

Answer (score 1):

You can create good icons (with transparency and multiple resolutions in .ICO format) in GIMP using [this tutorial](http://demosthenes.info/blog/467/Creating-MultiResolution-Favicons-For-Web-Pages-With-GIMP).

It's good to know that .ICO is the only file format that works consistently good for all browsers.